# UITableView indexPathForCell: return nil in iOS10 with Xcode8 (Swift2.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios10, swift2

On same condition, iOS9 is Good, but can't get indexPath for cell in iOS10.

**self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell):**
`nil`

Now, I found that the cell is NOT in visibleCells in iOS10.
It is the problem.

Comment: `indexPathForCell` return optional `(NS)IndexPath?` object so it may be possible that it will `nil`, show the code where you are calling this method.

Comment: in iOS9 with same condition, then returning the index path, but in iOS10 there is no returning the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS10, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called at early time.
So, Then, `indexPathForCell` is `nil`, because the cell is NOT visible.

The solution I found is this.

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)
}
```